# How to import python module from different directory, same level, but different folder

Tags: python, import, python-import

I have a directory structure like

```
Documents/
    Project_1/
        module_1.py
    Project_2/
        module_2.py
```

If I want to import module_1.py into module_2.py, what is the syntax for it?

I have tried variations on

```
import ../Project_1/module_1
```

And

```
from .Project_1 import module_1
```

But I can't get it to work and have only done this once before in another project.

Comment: `import Documents.module_1` should work I guess, Not sure though

Comment: Possible duplicate, it is the second question talking about almost the same thing within a week.

Comment: I did a search and others have similar problems, but not the same.

Comment: You need to make Documents, Project_1, and Project_2 into packages.  There are many other questions about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a crude solution, but I ended up with something like this:

```
#This thing modifies the path
from sys import path

#This gets our user directory
from os import environ

#add module_1's location to path
path.append(environ['USERPROFILE'] + "\\Documents\\Project_1")

#import it now
import module_1
```

This is not the most elegant solution, but it can work on almost any Windows machine, assuming the folders are placed in their Documents.

The code about Environ could be reasonably replaced to match another directory, though.

Answer (score 1):

You have two alternatives;

```
from Documents.project_1 import module1.py
```

or

```
import Documents.project_1.module1.py
```

Comment: I get "ImportError: No module named 'Documents'"

Documents is a folder, not a module.